# Resources in Spring Boot Appliacation

Tags: java, spring-boot, resources, graceful-shutdown

I have developed a Spring Boot Application and I am looking for a comprehensive list of all the resources that needs to be cleaned or taken extra care of before killing the app. To name a few, the Database Connection pool needs to be cleaned. What are the other resources that I should take care of to graceful shutdown the app? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to explicitly clean any of the resources, Spring boot is intelligent enough to clean any resources that it was using.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: For example, if I am shutting down application manually by getting the connector port of Tomcat then also it will clean the resources on its own?

Comment: should have been a comment